# git-completion.bash and .bash_profile Erro

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

I was trying to edit my bash profile and it was a epic fail. I tried to search for an answer online but no luck. Now everytime I open my Terminal this message always appear.

```
Last login: Tue Jun 30 01:19:29 on ttys000
-bash: /Users/<username>/bin/git-completion.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/<username>/.bash_profile: line 114: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /Users/<username>/.bash_profile: line 114: `alias ip1="ifconfig -a | perl -nle'/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1'"'
<username>-MacBook-Air-2:~ <username>$
```

I basically tried to copy and past this guy's bash profile [Bash Profile](http://blog.taylormcgann.com/tag/prompt-color/) (the code under "conclusion") and for some reason it didn't work and I googled how to reset the bash profile by copy and past this code on the command line

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH
```

Please help. Thanks!

P.S. I am using MacBook Air OSX Yosemite version 10.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is referring to a file he made for custom bash completion of git commands. You can remove that, originally line 6:

```
source ~/bin/git-completion.bash
```

For the second error, there are some unneeded characters in the alias, change line 114 to:

```
alias ip1="ifconfig -a | perl -nle'/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1'"
```